# How to use "for" to set the background image of a group of buttons in a C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use a wheel to change (for example) 30 buttons' background image each time a form loads.

I cannot use this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=30;i++)
{
    button i .backgroundimage=image.fromfile("URL");
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible interpretations of your problem. Why can't you use your code? There are also different solutions for your problem.

As example:

```
    public Form1() // Constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // Ensure all controls are created.

        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(30);

        buttons.Add(mybutton1)
        buttons.Add(mybutton2)
        // Go futher with all your buttons.
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) // Create a load event
    {
       foreach(Button button in buttons)
       {
          button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(path);
          // Note: The file remains locked until the Image is disposed!
       }
    }
```

Comment: I want to set especial image for each button when form loads.how can I do this with this code?

Comment: Include this function in a method you can use this by invoke the method after `InitializeComponents()`. Not sure what you really try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use something like this assuming this code executes in a Form_Load and the buttons Parent control is your form. Have in mind that you should supply the real path to your image that you want to set as a background image

```
string path = "rootNameOfTheImage";
int counter = 0;
foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if(ctrl is Button)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)ctrl;
        if(/* test if this button should be used */)
        {
            btn.BackgroundImage=Image.FromFile(path + counter++.ToString() + ".jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to set especial image for each button when form loads

Comment: Then load image in every loop pass but name images the way that you can access them according to the button name or adding to the name some counter value.

Comment: I don't know if its true but I think I can do sth with tab Index in properties of each button,but don't know how

Comment: or you can set the image path in a button's Tag property. Just cast it to string

Comment: One problem with this method is that it prevents you from giving your buttons more appropriate names, and results in the application breaking when a control is renamed (which is generally a bad idea; being able to refactor code in that way is often desirable).

Comment: I don't see where this method requires specific names. The only thing that should be taken care of is the order of adding buttons to its container.